# Application Insights stop working after deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I set up Application Insights on my asp.net core (2.2) app. I can see data in Azure portal when I run my application locally. However, once I deploy it to App Service in Azure, Application Insights stop working - there is no data flow at all. Are there any additional steps I am missing?

Comment: You might have lost or overwritten the [telemetry instrumentation key guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/separate-resources) when you deploy - if you have multiple environments you'll want to move that to configuration.

Comment: How have you specified instrumentation key? The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Stuart's comments- > If you edited ApplicationInsights.config, kindly check the configuration of TelemetryInitializers and TelemetryProcessors. An incorrectly-named type or parameter can cause the SDK to send no data.
Also, in the Application Insights portal, open Diagnostic Search. Data usually appears here first. Refresh to see if it helps.
If feasible, you may restart the app and check to see if that helps.